# Django Rest framework, retrieve data from database with no related model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-database

I am trying to create a REST API for a database that already exists. The problem is that the data on the database are refreshed from a bash script every hour, so there is no related model for these data. So I am working on creating a GET request on Django so to be able to retrieve the data. Currently I am using an **APIView** like this:

```
class RetrieveData(APIView):

    def get(self, request):

            conn = psycopg2.connect(host=..., database=..., user=..., password=..., port=...)

            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(f'Select * from ....')
            fetched_data = cur.fetchone()
            cur.close()
            res_list = [x for x in fetched_data]
            json_res_data = {"id": res_list[0],
                             "date": res_list[1],
                             "data": res_list[2]}

            conn.close()
```

The problem that I have is that connecting on the database every time so to retrieve the data and then return the response is quite slow ~ 2sec/request. Also I am afraid in case of many requests made at the same time, how is that going to work.

So the question that I have is if there is any suggestions or any solutions that you propose.

Comment: Why don't you have models for these tables? Django has solutions for dealing with pre-existing or legacy databases. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: Agree with Abdul, you can probably make models for these pre-existing tables. In the case that you do need a raw connection to the database, you can still use Django's connection pooling. `from django.db import connection` and `cursor = connection.cursor()`. If the tables are not in your default database, you'll need to define the database in your settings file and get the right connection fro `django.db.connections`. That is a separate question.

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for your time, this is somethings that I am going to try!